# beamer -- making visible a part of an invisible block (theorem)

Tags: beamer, uncover

I have the following problem:

I have a theorem and want to show only one part of it first, without showing the head of the theorem. I tried:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Malmoe}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{A title}
\onslide<1->{Motivational text.}
\visible<3->{
\begin{theorem}
We have that
\begin{align*}
\visible<2->{\sqrt{\pi}} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} \text{d} x
\end{align*}
\end{theorem}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

what I get:
[image]

what I want:
[image]

EDIT:

the improved code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Malmoe}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}


\definecolor{seagullgray}{HTML}{CCCCCC}

\begin{frame}{A title}
\onslide<1->{Motivational text.}
\only<1-2>{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=seagullgray}}
\begin{theorem}
\visible<3->{We have that}
\begin{align*}
\visible<2->{\sqrt{\pi}} \visible<3->{= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\text{d} x}
\end{align*}
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

yields
[image]

In this compiler the color #CCCCCC doesnt even seem to fit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe a bit hacky but one could simply change the colour of the title to hide it:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Malmoe}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{A title}
\onslide<1->{Motivational text.}
\only<1-2>{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=bg}}
\begin{theorem}
\visible<3->{We have that}
\begin{align*}
\visible<2->{\sqrt{\pi}} \visible<3->{= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} \text{d} x}
\end{align*}
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With another colour theme:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Malmoe}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{A title}
\onslide<1->{Motivational text.}
\only<1-2>{%
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=bg,bg=bg}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=bg}
}
\begin{theorem}
\visible<3->{We have that}
\begin{align*}
\visible<2->{\sqrt{\pi}} \visible<3->{= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\text{d} x}
\end{align*}
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Off-topic: You don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` nor `\usepackage{xcolor}` with beamer

Comment: Wow! I have not such good imagination and was developing a tikz overlay solution. (+1)

Comment: This is a good idea. But unfortunately I use the colortheme seagull. There the Theorem environment has a gray background. I adapted your answer to this insofar that I set the block title color to #CCCCCC. (+1). But the background stays gray of course.

Comment: @Falrach If you could make a MWE that demonstrated the problem, I'm sure it can be fixed.

Comment: @koleygr Thanks for the vote. Using tikz overlay is actually also a very good idea. If you already have something it might be interesting to post it as an answer - I would surely upvote it!

Comment: @samcarter I have edited my answer and added the adapted code.

Comment: @Falrach Thanks for your edit! can you try with `\only<1-2>{
 \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=bg,bg=bg}
 \setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=bg}
}`?

Comment: @Falrach Or if you want to keep the box and just hide the font: `\only<1-2>{
 \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black!20}
}`

Comment: @samcarter I want to hide the box too. Your approach works partially. What is the analogue for the block headbox like "block body"?

Comment: @Falrach Hiding the box is what https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449998/beamer-making-visible-a-part-of-an-invisible-block-theorem/450003?noredirect=1#comment1130935_450003 does, isn't it?

Comment: No. The block headbox stays gray. Just the contentbox gets white.

Comment: @Falrach See the image I added to my answer. ` \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=bg,bg=bg}` should make the title box white.

Comment: Oh yes. I missed this part.

Comment: @Falrach :) :) :)